# centos not update, centos 7.8 (2003)

Tags: centos7

```
 dnf -y upgrade http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/centos-release-8.1-1.1911.0.8.el8.x86_64.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 0:35:45 ago on Tue May 12 20:59:10 2020.
centos-release-8.1-1.1911.0.8.el8.x86_64.rpm     55 kB/s |  21 kB     00:00    
Dependencies resolved.

 Problem: cannot install the best update candidate for package centos-release-7-8.2003.0.el7.centos.x86_64
  - nothing provides centos-gpg-keys = 8.1-1.1911.0.8.el8 needed by centos-release-8.1-1.1911.0.8.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides centos-repos = 8.1-1.1911.0.8.el8 needed by centos-release-8.1-1.1911.0.8.el8.x86_64
================================================================================
 Package            Arch       Version                   Repository        Size
================================================================================
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 centos-release     x86_64     8.1-1.1911.0.8.el8        @commandline      21 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Skip  1 Package

Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I want to update centos 7.8, I can’t get help.
first there was version 7.2, I upgraded to 7.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date the release date corresponds to the release, at the moment this is the latest release, the problem was in the kernel, tried to install on OpenVz, centos does not work does not support open. So tnank you.

Answer (score 0):

yes the gpg need also submitted to the download.

Try this:

dnf install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/{centos-release-8.1-1.1911.0.9.el8.x86_64.rpm,centos-gpg-keys-8.1-1.1911.0.9.el8.noarch.rpm,centos-repos-8.1-1.1911.0.9.el8.x86_64.rpm} (should be the newest release)